# Silex 404 / htaccess - app/src/www structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex

Here is the URL I want : http://localhost/project/api/ and the error is :

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

My structure, and I have 2 htaccess in api et api/www :

```
- project
-- api
--- app
--- src
--- www
```

The project/api/ :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# project/api/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The project/api/www htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# project/api/www/.htaccess
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For RewriteBase I tried to append /project/api/www/ but it didn't work too.

When the URL is http://localhost/justwrite/api/www/ I get my 'hello world'

**EDIT :**
Here is my project/api/www/app.php :

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
echo 'test';
$app->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello ';
});

$app->run();
```

The weird thing is "test" appear with the URL http://localhost/project/api/.

**EDIT 2:** If I put :

```
$app->get('project/api/', function () {
    return new Response('Welcome');
});
```

'Welcome' is showed maybe there is a parameter I can set in Silex to have this syntax :  `$app->get('/', ...)` ?

Comment: are you enable mod_rewrite module from apache.

Comment: Yes in the httpd.conf I uncommented the LoadModule rewrite_module (OSX) and I also have AllowOverride All.

Comment: can u check with adding this rule also Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

Comment: It didn't change anything. I added my app.php in my post if it can help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have found rewrite rules to be cumbursome. They end up working but somehow it always takes some fighting. In this case there is an alternative: [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). If your version of apache is 2.2.16 or higher you can replace the rewrite rules the code below. Add this to your two .htaccess file (one in each folder):

```
# silex rewrite rule
DirectoryIndex /app.php
FallbackResource /app.php
```

Replace app.php by the silex php file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't works too. Seems like the resource can't be found because it gave me a listing of my folder. In my root htaccess I have just this : 
`DirectoryIndex /www/app.php 
FallbackResource /www/app.php`
And in www htaccess :
`DirectoryIndex /app.php
FallbackResource /app.php` (I have the mod_dir enabled and Apache > 2.2.16)